# How to execute a given command in a new screen?

Tags: gnu-screen

I wish to rejoin an existing screen (there is only one on my system) kill window 6:

```
screen -r -p 6 -X kill
```

and execute the following command in a new window:

```
cd /opt/stack/neutron && python /usr/local/bin/neutron-dhcp-agent --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron.conf --config-file=/etc/neutron/dhcp_agent.ini
```

All I know is `screen -r -X screen` will start a new window (numbered 6) but how do I execute the above command in that window?

Answer (score 1):

Try to `screen` sub command.

```
screen -r -x -X screen 6 bash -c 'cd /opt/stack/neutron && python /usr/local/bin/neutron-dhcp-agent --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron.conf --config-file=/etc/neutron/dhcp_agent.ini'
```

NOTE: This window(window number 6) is automatically closed if last command (this case is python invoked from bash) ends.